# SVG: Vertical rotating animation

Tags: animation, svg

I'm new to SVG and experimenting.
I have done an animation with a rotating circle and another circle that goes vertical. Now I'm trying to combine those animations into one circle, making it go vertical and rotate at the same time. I can't figure out how to do that. My code so far looks like below. The animations separately works but not together. Any tips?

```
<svg width="200px" height="300px">
<circle cx="50" cy="200" r="20" width="100" height="40"
    style="stroke: #ff00ff; fill:none; stroke-dasharray:10, 5; stroke-width:2;" >

  <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                    type="rotate"
                    values="360 50 200; 0 50 200; 360 50 200"
                    begin="0s" dur="5s"
                    repeatCount="indefinite" />

  <animate attributeName="cy" 
         begin="0s" dur="2" 
         values="20;250;20"
         repeatCount="indefinite" />
</circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Here's a live demo, with a fixed viewBox so that the entire animation can be seen: http://jsfiddle.net/AK64q/

Comment: Your demo appears to work for me on Safari v7.0.1 on OS X. What browser/UA are you testing with? What OS? What version? And may I suggest making a simpler animation that is far easier to understand?

Comment: @Phrogz I'm using win7 and I have tried on Chrome 31.0, Opera 12.16, FF 26.0. It looks the same on all of them. With the animations combined, the circle rotates and jumps all over the place, not vertically.

Comment: Your intent is still not clear. Let me guess: do you want the circle to rotate around its center, while sliding up and down? Like a car wheel spinning as the car is being lifted up and down?

Comment: @Phrogz I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. Yes, that's what I'm trying to achieve. If you test the animations one by one separately, you'll see the circle either rotating or going up and down vertically. So I'm trying to combine those, making the circle rotate around its center while going vertically. Just including both animations in the circle didn't work as I expected it to. Is it possible to achieve the way I've put my code?